# В tkinter не получается развернуть оба фрэйма на весь экран

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Как бы я не организовывал взаимодействие между Nootebook и Frame, не получается развернуть вторую рамку на весь экран. Применяя метод pack() к frame, frame_1 получаю тот же результат. Как задать такие же ширину и длину второй рамке, как и первой?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
w_scr = screensize[0]
h_scr = screensize[1]

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Программа для поиска деффектов на изображении')
window.geometry(f'{w_scr}x{h_scr}+0+0')
window.state('zoomed')

nb = ttk.Notebook(master=window)

frame = ttk.Frame(master=nb)
nb.add(frame, text='вкладка 1')

frame_1 = ttk.Frame(master=nb)
nb.add(frame_1, text='вкладка 2')

nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

window.update()

print(frame.winfo_height(), frame.winfo_width())
print(frame_1.winfo_height(), frame_1.winfo_width()) # ну почему?
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1 1 показывает потому второй фрейм скрыт на момент принта. Если цвет фона фреймов поменять, то будет видно, что они всю доступную область занимают.

Comment: Ну или можно привязаться к событию переключения вкладки (`"<<NotebookTabChanged>>"`), и при переключении печатать размеры - будет видно, что при переключении на вторую вкладку покажет, что она тоже развернута